# Using usort() on multidimensional alphanumeric array (numbers first)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

Here is an example array I am attempting to sort:

```
$array = (object)array(

    'this' => 'that',
    'posts'=> array(
        'title' => '001 Chair',
        'title' => 'AC43 Table',
        'title' => '0440 Recliner',
        'title' => 'B419',
        'title' => 'C10 Chair',
        'title' => '320 Bed',
        'title' => '0114'
    ),
    'that' => 'this'
);

usort($array->posts, 'my_post_sort');
```

Here is the function I am using to sort:

```
function my_post_sort($a, $b) {

    $akey = $a->title;
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]*$',$akey,$matches)) {
      $akey = sprintf('%010d ',$matches[0]) . $akey;
    }
    $bkey = $b->title;
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]*$',$bkey,$matches)) {
      $bkey = sprintf('%010d ',$matches[0]) . $bkey;
    }

    if ($akey == $bkey) {
      return 0;
    }

    return ($akey > $bkey) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

This gives me the following results:

```
'posts', array(
    'title' => 'C10 Chair',
    'title' => 'B419',
    'title' => 'AC43 Table',
    'title' => '320 Bed',
    'title' => '0440 Recliner',
    'title' => '0114',
    'title' => '001 Chair'
)
```

Now, the last step I need is getting the numbers to appear (descending) before the letters (descending).

Here is my ***desired*** output:

```
'posts', array(
    'title' => '320 Bed',
    'title' => '0440 Recliner',
    'title' => '0114',
    'title' => '001 Chair',
    'title' => 'C10 Chair',
    'title' => 'B419',
    'title' => 'AC43'
)
```

I've tried all kinds of sorts, uasorts, preg_match, and other functions; and just cannot seem to figure out the last step.

Any suggestions or assistance?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this comparing function:

```
function my_post_sort($a, $b) {

    $akey = $a->title;
    $bkey = $b->title;

    $diga = preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $akey);
    $digb = preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $bkey);

    if($diga && !$digb) {
        return -1;
    }

    if(!$diga && $digb) {
        return 1;
    }

    return -strcmp($akey, $bkey);
}
```

It will sort in descending order, but place digits before other symbols.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work.  I think the way the titles are structured is causing this to not work??  All titles can/probably will end with letters.  Let me please adjust my question to reflect the additional array items.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to add "/" symbols in preg_match. Corrected.

Comment: Still not there.  I'm trying to set up a php fiddle now.  I still think it has to do with how titles are structured.

Comment: How did you get the url to the php lite fiddle?  I have one, but I don't know how to "grab" the url to it?  Thank you for your continued patience!

Comment: AHHH... got it got it :)  You are an ALL-STAR!  Thank you so much.  Now I can reverse engineer your code and help me understand.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Just click "Save As" button, then choose "Save the code in public status" and it will print different links including lite fiddle. You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not think your array can works... You can not have the same key many times on the same array level.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $title) {

        if ( is_numeric(substr($title, 0, 1)) ) {
            $new_array[$key] = $title;
        }
    }

    array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING);
    array_multisort($new_array, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $sorted_array = array_merge($array, $new_array);
```

Comment: Thank you. That works fine with same results as my function; and MUCH cleaner.  However, the final array is still not sorted with numbers first.  How would I move the numbers (descending) to appear before the letters (descending)?  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you wanted desc, now I fix it.

Comment: Numbers always are less than letters, so in your case, this function would be enough.

Comment: The results are sorting like ('C10 chair', 'B419', ..., '0440 Recliner', '0014.  I please need it like this ('0440 Recliner', '0014. ..., 'C10 chair', 'B419').

Comment: Yes, I messed up, letters are bigger... Try that.

You must assign different key for each one.

Comment: I was able to get it with @stant's solution.  Not that yours is wrong in any way; I was just able to get his working first.  THANK YOU for your time and consideration.  People like you help keep the open-source world going 'round.  Thank you.